# trying to let the motor stop when press the two push button

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, avr

I am working on a project and it has two push buttons, each one of them turns the motor in a direction (clock/anti clock wise) via H-bridge, however I am trying to let the motor stop when I click both of the push buttons. Everything is working fine but I can't get the two push buttons part...

Here is my attempt:

```
#include "motor.h"
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>
int flag=0;

int main(void)
{
    DDRD &= ~(1<<PD2);
    DDRD &= ~(1<<PD3);
    DDRB |= (1<<PB0);
    DDRB |= (1<<PB1);
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB0);
    PORTB &= ~(1<<PB1);

    while(1)
    {
        if (PIND & (1<<PD2))
        {
            flag = 1;
        }           
        else if (PIND & (1<<PD3))
        {
            flag = 2;
        }           
        else if (PIND & (1<<PD3 ) && (1<<PD2))
        {
            flag = 3;
        }

        switch (flag)
        {
            case 1:
                 DC_MOTOR_PORT |= (1<<DC_MOTOR_PIN1);
                 DC_MOTOR_PORT &= ~(1<<DC_MOTOR_PIN2);
                 break;

            case 2:
                 DC_MOTOR_PORT |= (1<<DC_MOTOR_PIN2);
                 DC_MOTOR_PORT &= ~(1<<DC_MOTOR_PIN1);
                 break;

            case 3:
                 DC_MOTOR_PORT=0x00;
                 break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what happens (or doesn’t) when you press both buttons?

Comment: i cant get it work ,i click both of them and nothing happens.

Comment: `if(PIND & (1<<PD3)&&(1<<PD2))`? Check what you intend, and operator precedence.

Comment: Oops edited comment: did you intend `if((PIND & (1<<PD3 | 1<<PD2)) == (1<<PD3 | 1<<PD2))`, or, `if((PIND & 1<<PD3) && (PIND & 1<<PD2))`

Comment: You need to de-bounce the buttons.

Comment: Yes debouncing. Also, how close together in time can you press and release both buttons? Would they both appear pressed/released to your code instantaneously - in the same sample of the inputs? And what if, once both are pressed, one is released slightly before the other, what should your code do to the motor?

Answer (score 5):

I *assume* that when you press one button, the `1 << PD2` pin in `PIND` becomes set. The condition `PIND & (1 << PD2)` becomes true, the `if` branch is taken, and the code doesn't bother to test other conditions (since they are under `else` clauses).

Besides, `&&` is a logical operation. `(1<<PD3 ) && (1<<PD2)` *always* yields `true`, so the `else` clause would effectively test for `PING & 1`. Not exactly what you want.

Consider instead

```
    button_state = PIND & ((1 << PD2) | (1 << PD3)); // Mask out pins of interest
    switch (button_state) {
        case 0: // Nothing pressed
            ....
            break;
        case 1 << PD2: // One button pressed
            ....
            break;
        case 1 << PD3: // Another button pressed
            ....
            break;
        case (1 << PD2) | (1 << PD3): // Both pressed
            ....
            break;
```

Comment: a proper debouching is also required.

Answer (score 0):

In the else-if construct, the last condition will never be tested because the first test `PIND & (1<<PD2)` will also be true.  Also the use of `&&` in the third test is incorrect.

A further problem is that you read `PIND` multiple times.  To ensure consistency you should read it once and test the value read.

You could test for the third condition (both buttons) first, but that is in fact unnecessary.  The whole construct can be replaced with:

```
uint8_t buttons = PIND ;
flag = 0 ;
if( buttons & (1<<PD2) )
{
    flag |= 1;
}

if( buttons & (1<<PD3) )
{
   flag |= 2 ;
}
```

Or more succinctly perhaps:

```
flag  = ( buttons & (1<<PD2) ) ? 1 : 0 ;
flag |= ( buttons & (1<<PD3) ) ? 2 : 0 ;
```

Then when both are pressed, flag will be `1 | 2` which is `3`.

Even that is probably unnecessary; you could just use the masked value of PIND directly in the switch.  That solution has already been posted by @user58697.